# Populate listview from JSONArray android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Basically this question is an update for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138634/change-static-to-dynamic-listview-in-fragment-from-json-android)

Just to rewind again, this is the country_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/gambar_saja"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/n1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail_country"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar_saja"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/gambar_saja"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/code"
        android:layout_below="@+id/code"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/continent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/region"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/continent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/continent"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is cari_studio.xml to populate the country_info into listview (listView1) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/isiArea"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/area"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/textArea"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/area"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_area_studio"
    android:layout_below="@+id/area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/cari_studio" android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/myFilter" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/studio_hint">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar_background"
        >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAll"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_allselector"
            android:text="All"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_pictureselector"
            android:text="Pictures"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_videoselector"
            android:text="Videos"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFile"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_fileselector"
            android:text="Files"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMore"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_moreselector"
            android:text="More"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/floatingmenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/laysemitransparentwithborders"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Contacts"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ff999999"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Calendar"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the Cari Studio Class to get JSONArray result (use post) and I already success get the result :

```
public class CariStudio extends Activity{
final Context context = this;
MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
RadioButton radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4, radioButton5;
TextView flexlocationid;
Spinner flexlocation;
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ArrayList<String> provincelist;
ArrayList<ProvinceModel> province;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cari_studio);

    //Generate list View from ArrayList
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
    addListenerOnButton();
}
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String token= extras.getString("TOKEN");
    radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);
    radioButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, home.class);
            intent.putExtra("TOKEN", token);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPicture);
    radioButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CariKelas.class);
            intent.putExtra("TOKEN", token);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVideo);
    radioButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CariStudio.class);
            intent.putExtra("TOKEN", token);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFile);
    radioButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HotStuff.class);
            intent.putExtra("TOKEN", token);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    radioButton5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMore);
    radioButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAccount.class);
            intent.putExtra("TOKEN", token);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    flexlocation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.textArea);
    flexlocationid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.isiArea);
}
private class SendfeedbackJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CariStudio";
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String token= extras.getString("TOKEN");
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String areaid = params[0];
        Utils.log("params 1:"+ areaid);
        // do above Server call here
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("region_id", areaid ));

        String responseString = null;
        final String url_studio = Constant.URI_BASE_AVAILABLE_STUDIO+ "?token=" + token;
        Utils.log("url studio:"+ url_studio);
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_studio);

            // no idea what this does :)
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            // This is the line that send the request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Utils.log("response:"+ response);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseAsText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Utils.log("daftar isi studio: " + responseAsText);
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(responseAsText);
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                final String studio_name = jsonobject.getString("studio_name");
                final String address = jsonobject.getString("address");
                final String website = jsonobject.getString("website");
                final String seo_url = jsonobject.getString("seo_url");
                Utils.log("studio_name: " + studio_name);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
                        Country country = new Country(studio_name,address, "Website:"+ website,
                                "Fasilitas:"+ seo_url);
                        countryList.add(country);
                        //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
                        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context,
                                R.layout.country_info, countryList);
                        //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
                        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                        // Assign adapter to ListView
                        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {
                                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                                Country country = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        country.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, checkin.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                        EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
                        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            }

                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                            }

                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*Toast.makeText(context,
                    "user not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.format("Error during login: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
        return "processing";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        //dialog.cancel();
    }
}
// Download JSON file AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the CariStudio Class
        province = new ArrayList<ProvinceModel>();
        // Create an array to populate the spinner
        provincelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        // JSON file URL address
        final String url_flexlocation = Constant.URI_BASE_FLEXLOCATION;
        Utils.log("url_flexlocation: " + url_flexlocation);

        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url_flexlocation);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Utils.log("data: " + data);
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                ProvinceModel worldpop = new ProvinceModel();

                worldpop.setId(jsonobject.optString("flex_id"));
                worldpop.setProvince(jsonobject.optString("name"));
                province.add(worldpop);

                // Populate spinner with province names
                provincelist.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in cari_studio.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.textArea);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CariStudio.this,
                        R.layout.spinner_white,
                        provincelist));
        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Locate the textviews in cari_studio.xml
                        TextView flexlocationid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.isiArea);

                        // Set the text followed by the position
                        flexlocationid.setText(province.get(position).getId());
                        String areaid = flexlocationid.getText().toString();
                        Utils.log("area id:" + areaid);
                        SendfeedbackJob job = new SendfeedbackJob();
                        job.execute(areaid);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    }
}
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    private ArrayList<Country> originalList;
    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;
    private CountryFilter filter;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.originalList.addAll(countryList);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
            filter  = new CountryFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        TextView name;
        TextView continent;
        TextView region;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.continent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.continent);
            holder.region = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.region);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Country country = countryList.get(position);
        holder.code.setText(country.getCode());
        holder.name.setText(country.getName());
        holder.continent.setText(country.getContinent());
        holder.region.setText(country.getRegion());

        return convertView;

    }

    private class CountryFilter extends Filter
    {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
            {
                ArrayList<Country> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Country>();

                for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    Country country = originalList.get(i);
                    if(country.toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(country);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = originalList;
                    result.count = originalList.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {

            countryList = (ArrayList<Country>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for(int i = 0, l = countryList.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(countryList.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
}
```

the result that I got from Utils.log("daftar isi studio: " + responseAsText) :

```
[{"id":"8","studio_name":"Dodi fit","seo_url":"dodi-fit","address":"Komp. Pertanian Blok 5 No 3","postcode":"87473","area_phone":"","phone":"+62876543","area_phone_second":"","phone_second":"+62","website":"sucifir.com","region_id":"12","lokasi_id":"138","booking_window":"7","facebook":"dodifitfb","twitter":"dodifittw","how_to_get_there":"over there, by trun left and right","priority":"5"},{"id":"11","studio_name":"inu fit","seo_url":"inu-fit","address":"","postcode":"","area_phone":"","phone":"+6221324234","area_phone_second":"","phone_second":"","website":"","region_id":"11","lokasi_id":"137","booking_window":"0","facebook":"","twitter":"","how_to_get_there":"","priority":"5"},{"id":"5","studio_name":"Vstudio","seo_url":"vstudio","address":"Plaza Indonesia Ground Floor #541","postcode":"","area_phone":"","phone":"+6221453787","area_phone_second":"","phone_second":"","website":"www.jkiij.com","region_id":"12","lokasi_id":"137","booking_window":"0","facebook":"face","twitter":"twy","how_to_get_there":"","priority":"5"},{"id":"7","studio_name":"Infovendor","seo_url":"infovendor","address":"","postcode":"","area_phone":"","phone":"+6221123452","area_phone_second":"","phone_second":"","website":"www.kidsdngf.com","region_id":"12","lokasi_id":"135","booking_window":"1","facebook":"","twitter":"","how_to_get_there":"","priority":"5"},{"id":"12","studio_name":"Seleb Fitnes One","seo_url":"selebfitnesone-57","address":"Kelapa gading timur no 17","postcode":"","area_phone":"","phone":"+6221453777","area_phone_second":"","phone_second":"","website":"selebfirnes.com","region_id":"12","lokasi_id":"138","booking_window":"0","facebook":"","twitter":"","how_to_get_there":"","priority":"5"},{"id":"14","studio_name":"Riri Studio","seo_url":"riristudio-57","address":"Mall Kelapa Gading, Lt 5","postcode":"","area_phone":"","phone":"+6221459325","area_phone_second":"","phone_second":"","website":"riri-riri.com","region_id":"12","lokasi_id":"135","booking_window":"7","facebook":"","twitter":"","how_to_get_there":"","priority":"5"},{"id":"19","studio_name":"NF Studio","seo_url":"nf-studio","address":"Ruko Mediterania Blok A4 No 79Jalan Ahmad Yani Kav A5, Kota Bekasi","postcode":"13536","area_phone":"","phone":"+62265111222","area_phone_second":"","phone_second":"","website":"nfstudio.com","region_id":"11","lokasi_id":"137","booking_window":"7","facebook":"","twitter":"","how_to_get_there":"","priority":"5"}]
```

and the result that I got from looping Utils.log("studio_name: " + studio_name) are :

```
studio_name: Dodi fit
studio_name: inu fit
studio_name: Vstudio
studio_name: Infovendor
studio_name: Seleb Fitnes One
studio_name: Riri Studio
studio_name: NF Studio
```

It means I already got all of it use looping. 
But the problem is the result did not populate into listview (it show as one one last result NF Studio, the other did not appear).

What I need is populate this into 4 texview from country_info (I disable imageview) :

```
String studio_name, address, website, seo_url
```

What is the correct code to show/populate that into listview?

Comment: I update the code, I added it into runOnUiThread inside for loop, but it only show one last result NF Studio, the other result did not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Add the values into a `List` and pass it to the `Adapter` class of your `ListView` inside `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need a thread, that's the whole point of async.
- List View code is in the for loop
- UI code belongs to `PostExecute()` not `doInBackground()`
- You reinitialized the list inside of the loop

Try like this:

```
private class SendfeedbackJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CariStudio";
    private ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String token= extras.getString("TOKEN");
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String areaid = params[0];
        Utils.log("params 1:"+ areaid);
        // do above Server call here
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("region_id", areaid ));

        String responseString = null;
        final String url_studio = Constant.URI_BASE_AVAILABLE_STUDIO+ "?token=" + token;
        Utils.log("url studio:"+ url_studio);
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_studio);

            // no idea what this does :)
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            // This is the line that send the request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Utils.log("response:"+ response);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseAsText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Utils.log("daftar isi studio: " + responseAsText);
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(responseAsText);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                final String studio_name = jsonobject.getString("studio_name");
                final String address = jsonobject.getString("address");
                final String website = jsonobject.getString("website");
                final String seo_url = jsonobject.getString("seo_url");
                Utils.log("studio_name: " + studio_name);
                Country country = new Country(studio_name,address, "Website:"+ website,"Fasilitas:"+ seo_url);
                countryList.add(country);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*Toast.makeText(context,
                    "user not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.format("Error during login: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
        return "processing";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        //dialog.cancel();
        //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context,
                R.layout.country_info, countryList);
        //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Country country = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        country.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, checkin.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: if inside runOnUiThread, it only show last result (NF studio), the other result did not appear.

Comment: Oh `private ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();` needs to be declared on the class level. see my edit

Comment: @TanyaKode the reason you see the last entry is because you have to move it out of the loop like I said in my answer

Comment: it show as blank result after I declare private ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>(); on class level and put dataAdapter on postexecute just like your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94049/discussion-between-meda-and-tanya-kode).